# Writing constructor of template class with template argument-depending parameters

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-meta-programming

Consider the following two classes with constructors that accept wildly different sets of parameters.

```
class A {
public:
  A(int x, double y) {
    //do something
  }
};

class B {
public:
  B(const std::vector<bool>& x) {
    //do something
  }
};
```

Now, I want to write a class template TpC that will have an object (which might be A or B or something else). In other words, I want to be able to use the following:

```
int x;
double y;
std::vector<bool> z;
TpC<A> obj_a (x, y);
TpC<B> obj_b (z);
```

How can I write a constructor for TpC that is dependent on the parameters of the constructors of A and B? It would be acceptable to write something like a trait/policy to tell TpC what the parameters should be for each particular specialization.

Comment: Careful, `std::vector<bool> z();` is the declaration of a function.

Comment: Do you just want to store the different data types or do you want to do something "similar" with the data, for example by calling a method "doSomething()" on an instance of A or B and the specific implementation of "doSomething()" correctly handles the data members? If so, you can also think of an abstract base class for A and B, which has a virtual method "doSomething()".

Comment: @O'Neil yes, most-vexing parse, I wrote this on a rush :) Thanks.

Comment: @tangoal The second. My use case is highly performance-sensitive. It was first implemented with virtual methods. Then moved to hard-code each would-be specialization, got significant speedup. Now I need to do this for a couple more specializations and the code is becoming a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use a template constructor. However, in order to prevent this constructor being called instead of the copy constructor, you need to add a bit of disambiguation. For example:

```
template<class T>
class TpC {
     T t;
public:
     struct in_place_t { };
     static constexpr in_place_t in_place;
     template<class... ARGS>
     TpC(in_place_t, ARGS... args) : t(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...) {}
};
```

In C++17 `in_place` is available in `std`.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a template constructor with [parameter pack](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for `TpC`. (As the comments suggested I used [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) to constrain template, otherwise it might be better match than copy constructor. See the whole code snippet from the link I posted.)

```
template <typename T, typename... U>
struct my_is_same {
    constexpr static bool value = false;
};
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... U>
struct my_is_same<T1, T2, U...> {
    constexpr static bool value = std::is_same_v<T1, std::remove_cvref_t<T2>>;
};
template <typename T, typename... U>
inline constexpr bool my_is_same_v = my_is_same<T, U...>::value;

template <typename T>
class TpC {
    T t;
public:
    template <typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<
                                             !my_is_same_v<TpC, Args...> &&
                                             std::is_constructible_v<T, Args&&...>
                                           >>
    TpC(Args&& ... args) : t(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
};
```

and then

```
int x;
double y;
std::vector<bool> z;
TpC<A> obj_a (x, y);
TpC<B> obj_b (z);
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sNSxx7pAnMrGtI41)

Comment: That will have VERY unpleasing effect of screwing up the copy constructor for holder class.

Comment: Care with template constructor, which might be better match than copy constructor. SFINAE might help in that regards.

Comment: @Jarod42 Tried.

Comment: There is still the (evil) case when `T` can be constructed with `TpC<T>`.

Comment: You can check that decayed 1st arg is not `TpC<T>` (when there are only one argument). It becomes complicated and verbose :/

Comment: @Jarod42 Just go the in_place route. This is what they use for `std::variant` constructor.

Comment: That's not the right way to check for constructibility.

Comment: @T.C. that being?

Comment: @SergeyA `is_constructible`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Tried again.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using c++11 or later, you can use a variadic template constructor with a parameter pack expansion calling std::forward on the constructor arguments. Something like:

```
template <typename T>
class TpC {
    T base;
public:
    template <typename... Args>
    TpC(Args&&... args)
    : base(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {
    }
};
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the one already posted and it suffers the same flaw if the original version of it.

Comment: I am sorry that typing on my phone made me slow enough that I went from typing when there where no answers to bring the third.