# Variadic templates and resolving overload ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, initializer-list, overload-resolution

When compiled, the code below generates the error noted on line 12; `make_vec` doesn't seem to know whether to call constructor A or B.

```
template<int N, typename T = double>
class vec {
    std::array<T, N> buf;
public:
    template <typename... Args, typename = std::enable_if_t<(sizeof...(Args) == N && N > 1)>>
    vec(Args&&... args) : buf({ std::forward<Args>(args)... }) {} // CONSTRUCTOR A
    explicit vec(std::array<T, N>&& arr) : buf(std::move(arr)) {} // CONSTRUCTOR B
};

template <typename... Args>
vec<sizeof...(Args), typename std::common_type<Args...>::type> make_vec(Args&&... args) {
    return vec<sizeof...(Args), typename std::common_type<Args...>::type>({ std::forward<Args>(args)... });
}     // THE LINE ABOVE GENERATES error C2440: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'vec<3,int>'
      //   note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

int main() {
    auto x = make_vec(1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a simple way to force `make_vec` to call constructor A while keeping the signatures of constructors A, B, and `make_vec` intact?

Comment: No way to confirm this atm, but the problem here seems to be the initializer list. Just use an explicit std::array constructor there and it should work. Note the variadic constructor seems superfluous with make_vec. Maybe you want one that takes a initializer list instead?

Comment: See the anwers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492960/writing-constructor-of-template-class-with-template-argument-depending-parameter/50493156)

Comment: remove the initializer list in make_vec... ( std::forward<Args>(args)... ); -> https://ideone.com/W0WgoH

Comment: Don't do `buf({ std::forward<Args>(args)... })`. That technically creates a prvalue which is then used to copy into `buf`. You're initializing an aggregate, so do `buf{ std::forward<Args>(args)... }` instead.